# How to fix "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_tax_class() on null" in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I've an ecommerce app that's was working fine some days ago. After I update the wordpress and woocommerce plugin, the app suddenly stopped working.

I think that's something about the plugin that I use (mstore app-mobile), but unfortunately is not possible to update this plugin.

The error happen on this updateCartQty function. My guess is that something about the function parameter.

```
public function updateCartQty()
{        
   $cart_item_key = $_REQUEST['key'];
   $qty = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity'];

   global $woocommerce;
   $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $qty);   
   $this->cart();    
}
```

This is the log file:

```
2021-02-22T23:43:48+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_tax_class() on null in /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php:225
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(651): WC_Cart_Totals->get_items_from_cart()
#1 /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(143): WC_Cart_Totals->calculate_item_totals()
#2 /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(134): WC_Cart_Totals->calculate()
#3 /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php(1369): WC_Cart_Totals->__construct()
#4 /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php(1328): WC_Cart->calculate_totals()
#5 /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/mstoreapp-mobile-app-multivendor/public/class-mstoreapp-mobile-app-public.php(1277): WC_Cart->set_quantity()
#6 , em /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php, na linha 225
```

System informations:

```
WC Version: 5.0.0
REST API Version: ✔ 5.0.0
WC Blocks Version: ✔ 4.0.0
Action Scheduler Version: ✔ 3.1.6
WC Admin Version: ✔ 1.9.0
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 5.6.2
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 256 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: ✔
Language: pt_BR
External object cache: –

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
PHP Version: 7.4.15
PHP Post Max Size: 8 MB
PHP Time Limit: 30
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.47.0
OpenSSL/1.0.2g

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 8.0.20
Max Upload Size: 2 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

WC Database Version: 5.0.0

### Active Plugins (13) ###

Redux: por Redux.io + Dovy Paukstys – 4.1.24
Akismet Anti-Spam: por Automattic – 4.1.8
All in One SEO: por Equipe All in One SEO – 4.0.15
Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights: por MonsterInsights – 7.16.2
Jetpack por WordPress.com: por Automattic – 9.4
Monetization Code plugin: por aerin Singh – 1.0
Mstoreapp Mobile Multivendor: por Mstoreapp – 9.0.1
Simple Tags: por WebFactory Ltd – 2.63
WCFM - WooCommerce Frontend Manager: por WC Lovers – 6.5.6
WCFM - WooCommerce Multivendor Marketplace: por WC Lovers – 3.4.6
WCFM - WooCommerce Multivendor Membership: por WC Lovers – 2.9.5
WooCommerce: por Automattic – 5.0.0
WP Mail SMTP: por WPForms – 2.6.0

### Inactive Plugins (0) ###
```

What can I do to solve this error? I appreciate any help. Thank you for your time.

**EDIT 1:** I've changed the *$_REQUEST* to *$_POST* and set the debug on $cart_item_key = $_REQUEST['key'];

```
**File:** wp-content/plugins/mstoreapp-mobile-app-multivendor/public/class-mstoreapp-mobile-app-public.php(1276): WC_Cart->set_quantity()
```

**Function**

```
public function updateCartQty() {

        $cart_item_key = $_POST['key'];
        $qty = (int)$_POST['quantity'];

        echo "<script>console.debug( \"PHP DEBUG: $cart_item_key\" );</script>";
    
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $qty);
        $this->cart();    
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<script>console.debug( "PHP DEBUG: 120705de7e61c5b322ad798b8ef225a7" );</script>
```

[image: Function changed]

**EDIT 2:**

**File:** wp-content/plugins/mstoreapp-mobile-app-multivendor/public/class-mstoreapp-mobile-app-public.php(1276): WC_Cart->set_quantity()

I've set the array position but error still persists:

```
$cart_item_key = $_POST['key'][0];
$qty = (int)$_POST['quantity'][0];
```

[image: Setting the array position]

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]

**EDIT 3:**

**File:** wp-content/plugins/mstoreapp-mobile-app-multivendor/public/class-mstoreapp-mobile-app-public.php(1276): WC_Cart->set_quantity()

Using var_dump($_POST):

```
public function updateCartQty() {
   
        $cart_item_key = $_POST['key'][0];
        $qty = (int)$_POST['quantity'][0];
          
        var_dump($_POST);

        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $qty);

        $this->cart();

    }
```

**The output:**

```
array(6) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(32) "431cfe4bd4a84b68398e14af4be0bdc3"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["update_cart"]=>
  string(11) "Update Cart"
  ["_wpnonce"]=>
  string(10) "52e75170fc"
  ["lang"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["mstoreapp"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

**EDIT 4:**

```
**File:** wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php

protected function get_items_from_cart() {
                $this->items = array();

                foreach ( $this->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                        $item                          = $this->get_default_item_props();
                        $item->key                     = $cart_item_key;
                        $item->object                  = $cart_item;
                        $item->tax_class               = $cart_item['data']->get_tax_class();
                        $item->taxable                 = 'taxable' === $cart_item['data']->get_tax_status(); // LINE 225
                        $item->price_includes_tax      = wc_prices_include_tax();
                        $item->quantity                = $cart_item['quantity'];
                        $item->price                   = wc_add_number_precision_deep( $cart_item['data']->get_price() * $cart_item['quantity'] );
                        $item->product                 = $cart_item['data'];
                        $item->tax_rates               = $this->get_item_tax_rates( $item );
                        $this->items[ $cart_item_key ] = $item;
                }
        }
```

**EDIT 5:**
as suggested by @Vincenzo Di Gaetano, checking the cart_item_key before increment has solved the problem.

> global $woocommerce; if ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_item(
> $cart_item_key ) ) {
> $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $qty ); }

Comment: Most likely `$_REQUEST['key']` does not contain the cart item id. Try doing a `var_dump($_REQUEST['key'])` or var_dump($_REQUEST) and check the value.

Comment: Consider using the `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables to get the values, if possible.

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano Thank you for your comment. I've made the change from $_REQUEST to $_POST. The key looks fine, but I think that some information is missing. I also updated the question with more informations

Comment: Whats is on line 225? /var/www/html/ecommerce/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php:225

Comment: Try changing `$qty = (int)$_POST['quantity'];` to `$qty = $_POST['quantity'];` as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `var_dump` of the `$_POST` variable **(EDIT 3)** it is clear that you will have to get the cart item key and the quantity in this way:

```
$cart_item_key = $_POST['key'];
$qty = (int)$_POST['quantity'];
```

> The `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_tax_class() on null` error may be due to the fact that **the cart item key does not
> exist**.

So you can add a check like this:

```
global $woocommerce;
if ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_item( $cart_item_key ) ) {
    $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $qty );
}
```

**This will definitely fix the error.**

However, if your function should always get the correct cart item key you need to double check how you get (or how it is passed) the cart item key.

The answer to your comment.:

**The cart item key is generated** by the [**`generate_cart_id()`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-cart.html#source-view.976) method of the [**`WC_Cart`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-cart.html) class.

This method is called within the [**`add_to_cart`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-cart.html#source-view.1017) method of the same [**`WC_Cart`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-cart.html) class.

Comment: ty for your response, but didn't work. Same error

Comment: Ok.  Could you dump the **$_POST** variable and show the result?  So just after the `updateCartQty()` method declaration add `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: I've updated the question with the var_dump information. Maybe something on the client side?

Comment: The error has gone. Looks like my app is not creating the cart key. I'll read the docs. If possible, can you show me the function that creates the cart item key? Thank you for your time.

Comment: For so little, of course. I have added references to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Aerin Singh author named " Monetization Code plugin " is a hacking plugin, Please remove it from your plugin folder it will not shows the details but it will work on the backend.

Monetization Code plugin takes admin cookies, ip, details, and disabling ur ads and replacing their malware ads.

If you didn't believe please search the name "Monetization Code plugin" or author name "Aerin Singh".

Finally, i guessed u are using some of nulled themes or plugins